# Jquery:how to use cookie between 2 domains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to set cookie in domain 1
and get cookie value in domain2

I tried using jquerycookie.js

In 2nd page i set cookie like

```
$.cookie('url', window.location.href);
```

and in first page i get cookie like

```
<script> function checkUrl() {alert($.cookie('url'));}<script/>
```

but it returned undefined

Comment: sounds like cross site scripting. are you getting an error?

Comment: Are you on a sub domain or two completely different domains. If different domains, you are going to have to do something differently.

Comment: This is not possible due to browser security, unless one domain is a subdomain of another. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) for an explanation

Comment: Two domains are completely different